# PHP PDF conversion

Tags: php, pdf

I am using PHP 5.0 pdf library to convert files dynamically into PDF. 
I am using this reference from the official PHP website using `PDF_new()`, creating its object and using `PDF_set_info` and `PDF_get_buffer` functions.

This works fine, but when I want to create PDF pages and writing the content inside of it, there is no reference given anywhere on how to convert an already existing page to PDF. Say a page in my folder `bill.php` with CSS too needs to be converted to PDF on the fly.

Comment: TCPDF,FPDF,MPDF54,HTML2PDF etc are available for pdf creation with php

Answer (score 1):

Well converting HTML to PDF is not that easy, there are several libraries out there that might fit your needs. But none has full html/css capabilities, especially not css3.

**FPDF**
http://www.fpdf.org

**TCPDF**
http://www.tcpdf.org

**DOMPDF**
http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/ (this class allows you to easily convert simple layouted websites to pdf. i used this class quite often with almost no problems. sadly this library does not support converting of forms to usable input fields.)

**WKHTMLTOPDF**
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ (actually a linux package but php wrappers are existing. this gives almost full html capabilities and awesome results)

Answer (score 1):

html2PDF is a nice library to use. Make sure you change the default language to English though. I've used it many times to create dynamic invoices with tables and divs. Works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Refer some of the articles, which may help to improve your knowledge as well as clear some of doubt of you.

1. [Getting started](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/11/4/2)
2. [Convert HTML To PDF in PHP The Easy Way](https://pdfcrowd.com/blog/2011/04/18/convert-html-to-pdf-in-php.html)
3. [How to Generate a PDF With PHP](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1414-how-to-generate-a-pdf-with-php/)
4. [Convert HTML to PDF](http://beebole.com/blog/general/convert-html-to-pdf-with-full-css-support-an-opensource-alternative-based-on-webkit/)
5. This [HTML to PDF SDK](http://htm2pdf.co.uk/blog/html-to-pdf-sdk/) may also help you.

Hope, it will help you.